# jsf and eclipse setup. Lib in Explorer is different than lib in tomcat. How come?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2

I am starter in JSF2.0, and I have a question related to Eclipse (I am using Helios).
1)I create a Dynamic Project
2)I add JSF project facet.
3)I choose JSF user library (I have created it using MyFaces)
All ok so far.
I notice though that in the Project Explorer in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` the lib directory is empty instead of having MyFaces jars.
The application works fine though.
I looked into this and the jars are actually being placed in the corresponding lib directory of the app deployed under `wtpwebapps` of the Tomcat instance of eclipse in the .pluggins directory.
Ok, it works but IMHO it is incorrect to have the Project Explorer inconsistent with the directories actually deployed.
I.e. lib is shown empty in Project Explorer but with jars under `wtpwebapps`.
Am I wrong to dislike this inconsistency?
Is this how it should work or am I doing something wrong in the way I am setting my project?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal for user-definied libraries. It's listed in libraries folder of the Java Resources folder. It's just an extra layer on managing libraries. If you dislike this, then choose *Disable Library Configuration* in the wizard and drop the JAR's in `/WEB-INF/lib` yourself.

Comment: @BalusC:So the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory under Project Explorer can only manually be updated?

Comment: No, you can also manage it by user-definied libraries. It only won't show up in the destination folder.

Comment: @BalusC:So each time I should look into the lib dir of wtpwebapps of tomcat to verify that they were copied there?

Comment: That's not necessary if you know/understand what user-definied libraries do.

Comment: @BalusC:My understanding is that I create a user-defined library containing the jars I want.I am not sure where eclipse keeps this info. Then when I create the project I choose my User Defined library. I can see the library under resources, but not under WEB-INF/lib. You are saying that I should just trust eclipse that these libraries will be also copied in the WEB-INF/lib of tomcat?

Comment: Yes, just one place to manage the libraries instead of manually copypasting them over a plethora of projects. And yes, as much as you trust Eclipse that it does on-the-fly compilation/validation, compiles all classes, packages the right WAR structure for you, etc.

Comment: @BalusC:I was wondering how come you removed your answer to my other question?Was almost correct.At least the exception part you solved it.

Comment: Well, I delete answers when it's either utterly wrong or simply was not worth the effort.